# NodeJs MySql multiple update

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a method in NodeJs using Express framework, in which I am **iterating an array and making an update in a Mysql DB**,
The Code receives a Connection object and a Post Body,
 
The Post Request Body is an Array of objects, of the data to be saved in the DB,
I am **trying to loop the objects one by one and save them in the DB using an Update Query**.

Now the strange part is, **the code works only if it gets called twice immediately**,
Ie. On testing I found out, **I have to make the API request twice in order for the code to save the data.**

**I get the following error on the first API call -**

```
Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

It's a simple Update call, I checked the MySql processes and there was no deadlock,

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

But the same code work's on the immediate 2nd API call.

```
let updateByDonationId = async (conn, requestBody, callback) => {

    let donations = [];
    donations = requestBody.donations;

    //for(let i in donations){
    async.each(donations, function(singleDonation, callback) {
        //let params = donations[i];
        let params = singleDonation;

        let sqlData = []
        let columns = "";

        if(params.current_location != null){
            sqlData.push(params.current_location);
            columns += "`current_location` = ?,";
        }
        if(params.destination_location != null){
            sqlData.push(params.destination_location);
            columns += "`destination_location` = ?,";
        }

        if(columns != ''){
            columns = columns.substring(0,columns.length-1);

            let sqlQuery = 'UPDATE donation_data SET '+columns
            +' WHERE donation_id = "' + params.donation_id + '"';

            conn.query(sqlQuery, sqlData, function (err, result) {
                logger.info(METHOD_TAG, this.sql);
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(METHOD_TAG, err);
                    return callback(err, false);
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            return callback(null, false);
        }
        columns = "";
        sqlData = [];
    },
    function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error(METHOD_TAG, err);
            return callback(err, false);
        }
        else{
           return callback(null, true);
        }
    });
    //return callback(null, true);

} // END
```

Also referring the following, i guess he was getting an ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT for weird reason as well -
[NodeJS + mysql: using connection pool leads to deadlock tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378350/nodejs-mysql-using-connection-pool-leads-to-deadlock-tables)

**The issue seems to be with the Non blocking Async nature of Node as rightly pointed out**

**Can anyone help with a correct code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.query()` the method is asynchronous, because of this your code tries to execute one query after another without waiting for the former to finish. On the database side, they just get queued up if they happen to affect the same portion of it, i.e., one query has a "Lock" on that portion of the database. Now one of the transactions has to wait for another to finish and if the wait is longer than the threshold value then the error which you are getting is caused.

But you said that you are not getting the error on the second immediate call, my guess is that during first call(s) the data was cached so therefore the second call was faster and it was fast enough to keep the wait under threshold value thus the error was not caused on the second call.

To avoid this all together and still maintain the asynchronous nature of code you can use [Promise](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) along with [async-await](https://javascript.info/async).

The first step is to create a Promise based wrapper function for our `.query()` function, like so:

```
let qPromise = async (conn, q, qData) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    conn.query(q, qData, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
            return;
        }
        resolve(result);
    });
});
```

Now here is your modified function which uses this Promise based function and async-await:

```
let updateByDonationId = async (conn, requestBody, callback) => {
    let donations = [];
    donations = requestBody.donations;
    try {
        for (let i in donations) {
            let params = donations[i];
            let sqlData = [];
            let columns = "";

            if (params.current_location != null) {
                sqlData.push(params.current_location);
                columns += "`current_location` = ?,";
            }
            if (params.destination_location != null) {
                sqlData.push(params.destination_location);
                columns += "`destination_location` = ?,";
            }

            if (columns != '') {
                columns = columns.substring(0, columns.length - 1);

                let sqlQuery = 'UPDATE donation_data SET ' + columns
                    + ' WHERE donation_id = "' + params.donation_id + '"';

                let result = await qPromise(conn, sqlQuery, sqlData);
                logger.info(METHOD_TAG, result); // logging result, you might wanna modify this

            }
            else {
                return callback(null, false);
            }
            columns = "";
            sqlData = [];
        }
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(METHOD_TAG, e);
        return callback(err, false);
    }
    return callback(null, true);
}
```

I wrote the code on fly so there maybe some syntactical error(s).

Comment: Getting error - let result = await qPromise(conn, sqlQuery, sqlData);
                               ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje make sure `updateByDonationId()` is an async function, i.e., has keyword  `async` in its definition/prototype line, like so: `let updateByDonationId = async (conn, requestBody, callback) => {`

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje Try running simple async-await example from the net and if you get the same error then you need to update your nodejs version.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the asynchronous nature of Node.js is going to be causing you issues here. You can try rewriting your loop. You can either use promises or the async.eachSeries method.

Try changing your loop to use the below:

```
        async.eachSeries(donations, function(singleDonation, callback) {
```

Comment: I've updated the code as per your suggestion, could you please cross check it? But this time when I call the API, I don't get and response from the API, not even error, could be my code issue, please help to check.

Comment: Does the code execute at all? Can you breakpoint inside the loop? It's going to be to do with the callback function not being called.

Comment: Yes the code runs, Debugger is also caught inside the query result block and shows 1 affected rows, but code is not getting coming inside the final function, Am I returning callbacks wrong?

Comment: If there is more than one value in the donations array then it looks like the callback inside the return of the conn.query might be dropping you out of the loop.

Comment: yes donations is an array, what would we the correct way to execute the array?

Comment: What happens when you remove the callback from conn.query?

Comment: Only the 1st element of donations array got executed, then things got lost.